# How to iterate over strings after newline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, newline

I am trying to compare these sentences with one another. For example, I would like to see if `BEFORE` is the same as `BEFORE THE` which is clearly not. However, the problem is I am trying to loop over the newlines, so

`BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS` would be only in only one string. Below is a sample file.

```
BEFORE

BEFORE THE

BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT

BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON

BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON
BRITAIN'S

BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON
BRITAIN'S RELATIONS

BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON
BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH
```

The way I'm doing it now loops through every single line. Hence when the sentence is in more than one line, it splits everything.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data = [d.strip().split('\n') for d in data]
```

How can I loop over this file, and get each sentences one by one, instead of looping over every single line?

Comment: Slightly confused. You have a file with those lines, exactly? You can delineate sentences by keeping track of empty lines. When there's an empty line, it's the end of the previous sentence.

Comment: You could use the `pairwise()` function shown in the documentation's [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()
    for line in text.split("\n\n"):
        line = line.replace("\n", " ")
        print(line)
```

I think this is what you want. You can split by double newlines, then replace newlines with spaces.

The output:

```
BEFORE
BEFORE THE
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS
BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your split on double newline, like:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = [d.strip().split('\n\n') for d in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split by double newlines:

```
data = f.read().split('\n\n')
```

However, you must ensure that the empty lines do not contain any characters (whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

One version using `itertools.groupby`. This will work with any number of newlines between sentences:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    txt = f_in.read()

out = []
for v, g in groupby(txt.splitlines(), lambda k: k != ''):
    if v:
        out.append(' '.join(g))


from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
['BEFORE',
 'BEFORE THE',
 'BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT',
 'BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON',
 "BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S",
 "BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS",
 "BEFORE THE PARLIAMENT ON BRITAIN'S RELATIONS WITH"]
```